# Problems with forloop and Points

Tags: c++, opencv

So  I'm trying too clean up my code as I was using too many Points written up. So I came up with the idea too use a forloop instead unfortunately I can't seem too get work.

I've changed my points into CVpoint arrays and made a forloop but I cant seem too get too work

Anyone know how I can make this work ?  My error is Can't convert CVpoint to Int

My functions :

```
    bool FindWhiteLine(Vec3b white)
    { 
bool color =  false;
uchar blue = white.val[0];
uchar green = white.val[1];
uchar red = white.val[2];
if(blue == 255 && green == 255 && red == 255)
        {
            color = true;
        }
        return color;
    }
    // extends the line until whiteline is found
    CvPoint DrawingLines(Mat img , CvPoint point,bool right)
    {
       int cols = img.cols;
       Vec3b drawingLine = img.at<Vec3b>(point); //defines the color at current positions
       while(point.x != cols){
        if(right == true)
        {
        point.x = point.x +1; //increases the line too the right
        drawingLine = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(point); 
        if(FindWhiteLine(drawingLine)){ // quites incase white line is found
            break; 
        }
    }
    else if(right == false)
        {
        point.x = point.x -1; //Decrease the line too the left
        drawingLine = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(point); 
        if(FindWhiteLine(drawingLine)){ // quites incase white line is found
            break; 
                }
            }
        }
        return point;
     }
```

My main :

```
void LaneDetector::processImage() {

    //http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html   Handeling images
    Mat matImg(m_image);
    Mat gray; // for converting to gray

    cvtColor(matImg, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Let's make the image gray 
    Mat canny; //Canny for detecting edges ,http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html

    Canny(gray, canny, 50, 170, 3); //inputing Canny limits 
    cvtColor(canny, matImg, CV_GRAY2BGR); //Converts back from gray

    // get matrix size  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html
    int rows = matImg.rows;
    int cols = matImg.cols;

    //Points 
    Point centerPoint;             // Old way
    Point centerPointEnd;  
    CvPoint startPos[4] , endXRight[4] , endxLeft[4]; // new way I tried

    for (int i = 0; i< 4; i ++) {
        startPos[i].x = cols/2;
        endXRight[i].x = DrawingLines(matImg,endXRight[i],true); // error here
        endxLeft[i].x = DrawingLines(matImg,endxLeft[i],false);
 }
          if (m_debug) {
    line(matImg, centerPoint,centerPointEnd,cvScalar(0, 0, 255),2, 8); 
      for (i = 0; i< 4; i ++) {
       line(matImg, startPos[i],endXRight[i],cvScalar(0, 0, 255),2, 8); 
       line(matImg, startPos[i],endXLeft[i],cvScalar(0, 0, 255),2, 8); 
    }
```

Error code :

```
   /home/nicho/2015-mini-smart-vehicles/project-template/sources/OpenDaVINCI-msv/apps/lanedetector/src/LaneDetector.cpp:176:25: error: cannot convert ‘CvPoint’ to ‘int’ in assignment
      endXRight[i].x = DrawingLines(matImg,endXRight[i],true);


  /home/nicho/2015-mini-smart-vehicles/project-template/sources/OpenDaVINCI-msv/apps/lanedetector/src/LaneDetector.cpp:177:24: error: cannot convert ‘CvPoint’ to ‘int’ in assignment
      endxLeft[i].x = DrawingLines(matImg,endxLeft[i],false);
```

Comment: And *where* do you get the error? Do you understand why you get the error (it says that you're trying to use a `CvPoint` structure as an `int`)?

Comment: I'm getting the error at          endXRight[i].x = DrawingLines(matImg,endXRight[i],true);

Comment: What's `DrawingLines`? Does it perhaps return a `CvPoint`, which you then incorrectly try to assign to the integer `x`? Should you perhaps be assigning it to `endXRight[i]`, which has the correct type, instead?

Comment: I've added the error too the main thread and according too the compiler the error is there @JoachimPileborg  , I find this weird as this should work.

Comment: @MikeSeymour DrawingLines is a function which extends the X value (X is a cordinate) of the point until it finds a white line.  This function took in a Point before and return a point instead of a CVpoint but appeartenly You need a CVpoint too make arrays of points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error couldn't be much clearer. The function returns a value of type `CvPoint`, and you try to assign it to a variable of type `int`. That can't be done because you can't convert `CvPoint` to `int`.

It looks like you want to assign to the point itself, not one of its co-ordinates:

```
endXRight[i] = DrawingLines(matImg,endXRight[i],true);
            ^ remove .x
```

Comment: Thanks! It compiles now but crashes/doesn't start up , but that's something I'll try too debug :) Quick question is there a way too make Point arrays instead of using CvPoints ? I've google a bit but couldn't find proper information about it

Comment: @Amazinjoey: Sorry, I've no idea what Points and CvPoints are. If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: @ Mike Seymour Will  do! Thanks for the help!